# Minecraft Command works in Console but not in a CommandBlock

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-commands

So I've programmed a Plugin for Minecraft. Now I've tested the command in the console, it works totaly fine. But when I run the copy pasted command in a CommandBlock, nothing happends and the CommandBlock says: "Unexpected Error occurred trying to execute that command".
Is there a way to get more Information about that error or to fix that?

## CommandBlock output and input:

[image: CommandBlock output and input]

## Command by using the console

[image: Command by using the console]

Comment: Can you show the code when you declare the command, and the code for the command ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the plugin prevents the execution from **server** console.

If this is true it will not work in a command block either.

Perhaps you can work around this by using the sudo command of the EssentialsX plugin.

```
/sudo @p syncaudio <args>
```

This executes the command as the closest player to the command block